# How to populate(add items) to listBox2 from selected item in listBox1?

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

I am tasked with figuring out how to populate a 2nd listBox with the associated `<S>` element values when selecting an item in listBox1.  The items in listBox1 are concatenated values of related(by Attribute value) `<V>` elements.

I have the following XML:

```
<ServiceHistoryArray>
    <RecordID>XD116067*401529</RecordID>
    <SWR>
        <V Idx="1">7932</V><V Idx="2">7932</V><V Idx="3">7932</V><V Idx="4">7932</V>
    </SWR>
    <Comments/>
    <Mileage>6</Mileage>
    <Operation>
        <V Idx="1">Z7000*WPDIP****PRE-DELIVERY INSPECTION - BASE TIME</V><V Idx="2">Z911*INC****ETCH WINDOWS</V><V Idx="3">B0048*WPBS4****FASCIA, FRONT BUMPER - REPLACE ONE PIECE</V><V Idx="4">9997*WPBS4****</V>
    </Operation>
    <CloseDate>1998-12-30</CloseDate>
    <OpenDate>1998-10-16</OpenDate>
    <PartsAmount>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V><V Idx="2">0.00</V><V Idx="3">166.32</V><V Idx="4">0.00</V>
    </PartsAmount>
    <LaborAmount>
        <V Idx="1">64.80</V><V Idx="2">3.60</V><V Idx="3">140.40</V>
    </LaborAmount>
    <Warranty>
        <S Idx="1">&#xfc;96&#xfc;0&#xfd;&#xfd;10232632&#xfc;4H&#xfc;1</S><S Idx="2">&#xfc;96&#xfc;0&#xfd;&#xfd;10232632&#xfc;4H&#xfc;1</S><S Idx="3">&#xfc;96&#xfc;0&#xfd;&#xfd;10232632&#xfc;4H&#xfc;1</S>
    </Warranty>
</ServiceHistoryArray>
```

I have the following c# code:

```
//  Linq query to find all service history line items
var queryDetail = from v in xdoc.Descendants("V")
            group v by (int)v.Attribute("Idx") into g
            select String.Join(" ", g.Select(x => (string)x));

//  Iterates through the linq query and populates listBox1 with the servcie history details
foreach (string serviceInfo in queryDetail)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(serviceInfo);
}
```

To clarify:

The LINQ Query takes all related(by Attribute value) `<V>` elements, concatenates them into a single line, and adds them to listBox1.

I need to have listBox2 display the appropriate `<S>` element when the related(by Attribute value) item is selected in listBox1.

Please advise if further clarification or information is needed.

07/29/2013:  No hits yet.  Is there something that I have omitted from my question that is needed to get help?

Comment: what if you change "V" to "S"?

Comment: @N4TKD by changing "V" to "S" are you referring to the LINQ query named queryDetail?  If so, that will simply populate the 1st listbox with the <S> elements.